# How to check super admin for WordPress multisite?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to check super admin in `wp_config.php` and I've tried the following code without any result.

```
if (get_super_admins()) {
    echo 'You are super admin';
}
```

Kindly help me thanks.

Comment: If my answer resolves your question can you please mark it resolved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if ( is_super_admin() ) {
    echo 'You are super admin';
}
```

It will not work in `wp-config.php` as a user has not been loaded at this stage. There is essentially no user to check for.

Use it in your theme `functions.php` file or custom plugin code.